# Anaconda Nvaigator Start Error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm on a Windows 10 PC 64 bit.  I kept receiving a message that the spyder install was not the latest version, so in the Anaconda Command Prompt - running as Administrator (because I would receive access denied errors if I didn't), I ran the following:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda update spyder
```

Now, I receive the following error message when I try to start Navigator (I've removed my username):

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py",
> line 636, in wrapper return fun(self, *args, **kwargs) File
> "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py",
> line 706, in cmdline ret = cext.proc_cmdline(self.pid)
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py",
> line 75, in exception_handler return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
> File
> "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py",
> line 113, in start_app if misc.load_pid() is None: # A stale lock
> might be around File
> "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\misc.py",
> line 384, in load_pid cmds = process.cmdline() File
> "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py",
> line 721, in cmdline return self._proc.cmdline() File
> "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py",
> line 639, in wrapper raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._name)
> psutil.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=4220
```

)

This happens even when I run Navigator as an Administrator.  I'm very new to Python programming and very stuck on how to resolve this.

I can run spyder without using the navigator.

Answer (score 2):

You have to ran Anaconda Prompt as administrator (right click, run as administrator) and then update package.

Comment: I did that when I first updated and it wouldn't run.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6006

I ran the following in Anaconda Prompt (as administrator):

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

Then, I ran Anaconda as administrator and it is working now.